# How to know the class passed as parather to the extended abstract class

Tags: java, parameters, abstract-class

I have a class called `NewsDAO` that extends the abstract class `AbstractDAO` and pass it the class `News` as paramether.

```
public class NewsDAO extends AbstractDAO<News> {
}
```

What I need is a method to know, starting from all classes called `***DAO`, the type of class passed as paramether to `AbstractDAO`.

I struggled with it for a while but I didn't find the way.

Thank you

Comment: I can say reflection can do that but i am not sure, Can you post all your class code

Answer (score 1):

You can get the full name of the class you are extending by this way:

```
String fullExtendedClassName = this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()
            .toString();
```

Then you just have to format your string and get the info between '<' and '>'

```
String extendedClassName = fullExtendedClassName.substring(fullExtendedClassName.
indexOf("<") + 1, fullExtendedClassName.indexOf(">"));
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: getActualTypeArguments is your friend, no?